# Linkedin share/ugc post api is not providing posts

Tags: rest, get, linkedin-api

I am using the following endpoint to retrieve posts in the page

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:xxxxx
```

Even though there are posts, getting empty elements array

```
{
    "elements": [],
    "paging": {
        "total": 1,
        "count": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "next",
                "href": "/v2/shares?count=10&owners=urn:li:organization:XXXXXXX&q=owners&start=0",
                "type": "application/json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the right credentials worked