# Linkedin share/ugc post api is not providing posts python requests

Tags: python, rest, get, python-requests, linkedin-api

I am using the following endpoint to retrieve posts in the page

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:xxxxx`

Even though there are 235 posts in total, getting empty elements array

```
{
    "elements": [],
    "paging": {
        "total": 235,
        "count": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "next",
                "href": "/v2/shares?count=10&owners=urn:li:organization:XXXXXXX&q=owners&start=0",
                "type": "application/json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I added `X-Restli-Protocol-Version : 2.0.0`

And i have the Following scopes in the LinkedIn API access token

```
r_organization_social
r_1st_connections_size
r_emailaddress 
r_ads_reporting
rw_organization_admin
r_liteprofile
r_basicprofile
rw_ads
r_ads
w_member_social
w_organization_social
```

I don't know where it is going wrong...

I found this issue here

[Linkedin share/ugc post api is not providing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739495/linkedin-share-ugc-post-api-is-not-providing-posts)

but it only says Using the right credentials worked
i don't quite understand what he meant by that

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved

All I needed was Admin access to the organization page...